# Using PowerShell to get AD Groups using C# returns only 256 records

Tags: c#, powershell

Here is the code that I am currently working with:
...

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Get-ADGroup -filter * -ResultPageSize 5120 ");

    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
    foreach (PSObject obj in PSOutput)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Properties["DistinguishedName"].Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Properties["GroupCategory"].Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Properties["GroupScope"].Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Properties["ObjectClass"].Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Properties["SamAccountName"].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

...

In the code, I have added the '-ResultPageSize 5120'. This change did increase the number of records to 1000. Using an ADExplorere tool, I know that I have over 2300 Distribution and Security groups combined. The code above returns only 1000 groups total. I have tried going directly to the '-Server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', it was no help with the issue.

I am using PowerShell 5 and VS 2019 C#

Any suggestions or code improvements will be beneficial as I am a newbie to Powershell.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to use powershell?

Comment: Yes, our security team has mandated that all AD activity has to use PowerShell.

Comment: Set the `-ResultSetSize` property to `$null`. Microsoft kind of contradicts itself as it says null is the default but it might be a fail safe to insure a crazy query isn't launched.

Comment: I am still getting only 1000 records with the `-ResultSetSize $null`